# Передача данных переменной PHP

Tags: php, переменные

Как перенести переменную $_SESSION из файла singin.php в файл authRedirect.php, что бы проверить авторизирован ли пользователь
Отрывок файла singin.php:

```php
$_SESSION['user'] = [
"id" => $user['id'],
"full_name" => $user['full_name'],
"avatar" => $user['avatar'],
"email" => $user['email']
];
```

Отрывок файла authRedirect.php

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header('Location: ...html');
  exit;
} else {
  header('Location: ...php');
  exit;`введите сюда код`
}
?>
```

Comment: А вас не смущает, что вы пытаетесь достать значение по ключу `user_id`, которого не существует?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

signIn.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = [
    "id" => $user['id'],
    "full_name" => $user['full_name'],
    "avatar" => $user['avatar'],
    "email" => $user['email']
];
```

authRedirect.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])) {
    header('Location: ...html');
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location: ...php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit]